# How to type special letters in latex?

Tags: latex, fonts, symbols

How to type the following special letters from European languages in latex?

ä, é, and L'

Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219853/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

\"{a}
\'{e}

Find more here:
[link text](http://consult.wikidot.com/latex#accent)

Comment: Do you know how to type "L'" as well? Thanks. I typed "L'" and "L\'", but both does ways do not display "L'" when it   generates the pdf file.

Comment: Actually I guess I can't help for that. I don't understand what is a L'

Answer (score 1):

Is this L the Unicode "Latin Capital (or Small) Letter L with Stroke" (used in Polish, among other languages)?

If so, try this:

```
Stanis\l aw Lem
```

or, to shout, this:

```
STANIS\L AW LEM!
```